# Why do two equivalent systems of equations produce a different result?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I've been reading a book about material and energy balance when I faced a confusing problem when solving a system of equations. I came to notice some new concepts (that were already there, but didn't put much attention to) that now I believe are more important than they seem. I think it is a math equation the one I have, it's also a simple one but I'd like to get a clear and correct answer before I draw my own conclusions.

System 1

$$0.09F_8+F_6=r_1-r_2$$
$$0.27F_8=r_2+0.13(1-x)F_1$$
$$0.5F_8=r_1+xF_1$$
$$0.09F_8=-3r_1-r_2+0.65(1-x)F_1$$
$$0.05F_8=-r_1-r_2+0.22(1-x)F_1$$

$F_6$,$F_8$,$F_1$,$x$,$r_1$ and $r_2$ are the variables

Now if I say that $N=xF_1$ I get the System 2

$$0.09F_8+F_6=r_1-r_2$$
$$0.27F_8=r_2+0.13(F_1-N)$$
$$0.5F_8=r_1+N$$
$$0.09F_8=-3r_1-r_2+0.65(F_1-N)$$
$$0.05F_8=-r_1-r_2+0.22(F_1-N)$$

For this system $F_6$,$F_8$,$F_1$,$N$,$r_1$ and $r_2$ are the variables

All the $F_n$ variables are mass stream flow rates, the $r_n$ variables are called reaction rates to account for the mass that "appears" or  "dissappears" from a stream flow rate of a certain compound when a chemical reaction takes place within the system and $x$ is the mole fraction of a compound in $F_1$. I mention this because for this systems of equations a **negative answer for any variable will not make any physical sense**, even for the reaction rates. This systems of equations arise using the principle of conservation of mass

I know there are six unknown variables and only five equations in each system. In order to solve this problem there is something called a **basis** that my book defines as

*As a further consequence of homogeneity of the balance equations, if none of the stream flow rates is assigned a value in the problem statement, then any one of the stream flows can be assigned an arbitrary magnitude for purposes of calculation*

And in case it is important what mentions of **homogeneity** is

*A system of equations in which values of a set of variables can be uniformly scaled such that the resulting values continue to satisfy the equations said is said to be homogeneous in those variables. Formally stated, an equation $f(x,y)=0$ two variables x and y are homogeneous in y if, given any solution $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ any constant times $\bar{y}$ is also a solution*

On practice it basically means that you *can assume the value of a stream flow rate*, that is I can assume that $F_8=100 \text{ mol}.$ so that your system of equations get reduced in unknowns and you are able to solve it. Oftenly when you have to assume stream flow rates the problem asks for a intensive property of the physical system, it can be, at what temperature does the products of whatever-unit will come out if I feed it a stream with such and such composition? to answer such type of questions it doesn't matter how much of a flow goes in or out you will get the correct temperature

So, what is the problem? In system one I assumed $F_1=100 \text{ mol/hr}$ to not deal with a non-linear equation and solved for the rest of variables, that way I got a negative result for $r_2$, that is an obvious red flag. But for System 2 I assumed $F_8=100 \text{ mol/hr}$ and got only positive answers. In my world it didn't had to matter which flow I chose to assume its value I shouldn't get such different results. If I had assumed the value for $N$ on system 2 I should still get positive values for every variable. **And to clarify, the equations are not wrong, I have already verified them many times.**

When solving for System 1 and the assumption $F_1=100 \text{ mol/hr}$ I got

- $F_6=15.88 \text{ mol/hr}$
- $F_8=45.08 \text{ mol/hr}$
- $F_1=100 \text{ mol/hr}$
- $x=0.03$
- $r_1=19.51\text{ mol/hr}$
- $r_2=-0.43382\text{ mol/hr}$

When solving for System 2 and the assumption $F_8=100 \text{ mol/hr}$ I got

- $F_6=28.24 \text{ mol/hr}$
- $F_8=202.72 \text{ mol/hr}$
- $F_1=100 \text{ mol/hr}$
- $N=10.72 \text{ mol/hr}$
- $r_1=39.28\text{ mol/hr}$
- $r_2=2.04\text{ mol/hr}$

Comment: How did you get $0.027F_8$ for the second system? Seems to be off by a factor of $10$. Also, it would be much nicer to read if you could list for each system which are variables and which are constants. For example is $x$ a constant or one of the variables. Furthermore, you say you have computed some solutions with a particular sign, could you share with us what you've got?

Comment: It was 0.27 didn't noticed I made a mistake, I will edit my post to include what you ask for

Comment: Did you check your calculations using computer? If so, did you use symbolic calculations? They should be precise in this situation. I was in this situation many times (I thought my calculations were 100% correct) only to find very tiny mistake which changes everything

Comment: Note that system 1 is *not* homogeneous, so part of your story does not apply.

Comment: @GerryMyerson why is it not?

Comment: @Esgeriath Now that you said that, I think I know what I did wrong :(

Comment: Should your last equation have two occurrences of $r_1$?

Comment: What Gerry Myerson means is that in the second equation you have a term where we have a product of $x$ and $F_1$, thus, the system is not homogeneous (if you scale every variable by $\lambda$, then this product gets scaled by $\lambda^2$ while the rest gets scaled only by $\lambda$). That was also the reason to ask to specify which are the variables. If $x$ was a constant, then this would be homogeneous.

Answer (score 1):

The two systems are mathematically equivalent, but you have solved both of them wrongly, probably because of computational mistakes.

The second system of equations can be reformulated as
$$
\underbrace{\pmatrix{0&0&-0.09&1&-1\\ 0.13&-0.13&0.27&0&-1\\ -1&0&0.5&-1&0\\ 0.65&-0.65&0.09&3&1\\ 0.22&-0.22&0.05&1&1}}_A
\ \pmatrix{N\\ F_1\\ F_8\\ r_1\\ r_2}
=\pmatrix{F_6\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0}.
$$
It can be verified that $A$ is an invertible matrix. Therefore
$$
\pmatrix{N\\ F_1\\ F_8\\ r_1\\ r_2}
=A^{-1}\pmatrix{F_6\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0}
=F_6A^{-1}\pmatrix{1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0}
=F_6\pmatrix{0.109195\\ 5.856322\\ 2.586207\\ 1.183908\\ -0.048851}.
$$
Hence the only nonnegative solution is $F_6=0$ and $N=F_1=F_8=r_1=r_2=0$. That is, in the original system, the only nonnegative solutions are $F_1=F_6=F_8=r_1=r_2=0$ and $x\ge0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take these three equations
$$0.27F_8=r_2+0.13(F_1-N)$$
$$0.09F_8=-3r_1-r_2+0.65(F_1-N)$$
$$0.05F_8=-r_1-r_2+0.22(F_1-N)$$
and eliminate $r_2$ by adding the first to each of the others:
$$0.36F_8+3r_1=0.78(F_1-N)$$
$$0.32F_8+r_1=0.35(F_1-N).$$
Now subtract the first of these from 3 times the second:
$$0.6F_8=0.27(F_1-N),$$
or
$$20F_8=9(F_1-N).$$
Then $$r_1=0.35(F_1-N) - 0.32F_8=0.206(F_1-N)$$
and $$r_2=0.27F_8-0.13(F_1-N)=-0.0085(F_1-N)$$
so it looks as if not all variables can be positive.